# javascript runs a method from other module too early

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a site that loads pages dynamically by injecting html elements with Javascript. I had it work correctly when I had all the code in one file. Now I'm learning to code in modules using webpack, but I have a problem. 
So as you can see, html file only has a navigation. By clicking on the menu javascript will inject template to the wed-spa div.

Problem is that when Home is loaded on window.load javascript also runs a method setPosition from TriCouple, which is supposed to style the html template elements that are injected from Couple.js, which is of course non existent at the moment of window.load.

To clear up the explanation, the proper behavior would be:
1. window loads up and injects Home template immediately,
2. when clicking on "Couple" from navigation it should inject Couple template,
3. the styling for Couple template should be applied via methods from TriCouple.js.

Problem:
javascript is trying to do number 3 while being in number 1 where Couple elements don't appear.

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900|Roboto:400,900|Tangerine&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/styles/css/style.css">


        <title>
            Wedding template
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid wed-home">
          <nav class="wed-nav navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">John and John</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                  <div class="navbar-nav">
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="couple">Couple</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="bridesmaid">Bridesmaid</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="groomsmen">Groomsmen</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="events">Events</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="story">Story</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="rsvp">RSVP</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="wed-spa"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="./temp/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my main app.js:

```js
import Home from './modules/Home';
import Couple from './modules/Couple';
import TriCouple from './modules/TriCouple';


var home = new Home();

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var loader = new Home;
  loader.loadHome();
})

var couple = new Couple();
var triCouple = new TriCouple();
```

Home.js

```js
class Home {
  constructor() {
    this.template = `
    <div class="wed-heading row">
        <div class="wed-heading-wrapper col">
            <h1>Angelo & Klaudia
                <br>
                <span class="std">Save the date</span>
                <span class="wed-date">22.08.2015</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
    this.homeMenu = document.querySelector("#home");
    this.spa = document.querySelector(".wed-spa");
    this.homeSection = document.querySelector(".wed-home");
    this.homeClick();
  };

  homeClick() {
    var that = this;
    this.homeMenu.addEventListener("click", function(){
        that.loadHome();
    })
  };

  loadHome() {
    this.homeSection.classList.add('wed-front');
    this.loadTemplate();
  };


  loadTemplate() {
    this.spa.innerHTML = this.template;
  }

}
export default Home;
```

Couple.js

```js
class Couple {
  constructor() {
//Start of HTML Template
    this.template = `
      <div class="message-popup"></div>
      <div class="wed-couple container">
          <div class="wed-couple-newlyweds wed-couple-bride">
              <div class="wed-couple-newlyweds-img wed-couple-bride-img">
                  <div class="wed-couple-name-row row">
                      <div class="wed-couple-desc wed-couple-name wed-couple-name-bride col-md-auto">
                          <h1>Klaudia Kim</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wed-couple-desc wed-couple-position wed-couple-position-bride col-md-auto">
                          <span>The Bride</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="wed-couple-newlyweds-message wed-couple-newlyweds-message-bride">
                      <span>Message from the Bride</span>
                  </div>

                  </div>
                  </div>

          <div class="wed-couple-newlyweds wed-couple-groom">
              <div class="wed-couple-newlyweds-img wed-couple-groom-img">
                  <div class="wed-couple-name-row row">
                      <div class="wed-couple-desc wed-couple-name wed-couple-name-groom col-md-auto">
                          <h1>Angelo Kim</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wed-couple-desc wed-couple-position wed-couple-position-groom col-md-auto">
                          <span>The Groom</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                      <div class="wed-couple-newlyweds-message wed-couple-newlyweds-message-groom">
                          <span>Message from the Groom</span>
                      </div>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    `;
// End of HTML Template
//DOM declaration
  this.spa = document.querySelector(".wed-spa");
  this.coupleButton = document.querySelector('#couple');
  this.homeSection = document.querySelector(".wed-home");

  //initialize methods
  this.loadCouple();

  };
// End Constructor

// Start methods
loadCouple() {
  var _this = this;
  this.coupleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    _this.homeSection.classList.remove('wed-front');
    _this.spa.innerHTML = _this.template;
  });
};






}


export default Couple;
```

Tricouple.js

```js
class TriCouple {
  constructor() {
    this.wedCouple = document.querySelector('.wed-couple');
    this.coupleButton = document.querySelector('#couple');
    this.wedCoupleBride = document.querySelector(".wed-couple-bride");
    this.wedCoupleBrideImg = document.querySelector(".wed-couple-bride-img");
    this.wedCoupleGroom = document.querySelector(".wed-couple-groom");
    this.wedCoupleGroomImg = document.querySelector(".wed-couple-groom-img");
    this.wedCoupleNewlyweds = document.querySelectorAll(".wed-couple-newlyweds");

  // Detect initial Viewport
    this.initialWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.initialWindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    this.diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.initialWindowWidth, 2) + Math.pow(this.initialWindowHeight, 2));

// Calculate sinus
    this.sineX = this.initialWindowWidth / this.diagonal

// Calculate angle for rotation
    this.sinDegree = Math.asin(this.sineX) * (180 / Math.PI);

    //Initiate methods
    this.setHeight();
    this.setPosition();

  };


  //SET HEIGHT
  setHeight() {
    this.wedCoupleNewlyweds.forEach((partner) => {
      console.log('log for each partner');
      partner.style.height = this.diagonal + 'px';
    })

  };
  //POSITION TO LEFT & RIGHT
  setPosition(callback, obj){
    this.wedCoupleBride.style.left = -this.initialWindowWidth + 'px';
    this.wedCoupleBrideImg.style.left = this.initialWindowWidth + 'px';
    this.wedCoupleGroom.style.right = -this.initialWindowWidth + 'px';
    this.wedCoupleGroomImg.style.right = this.initialWindowWidth + 'px';
    callback.call(obj, null);
  }
}


export default TriCouple;
```

Comment: I think var couple = new Couple(); in the app.js could be the problem as it is getting initialized in the app.js... Ideally it should be initilalized when you click on the couple link.

Comment: @SrikantSahu Thanks!! I did think about similar solution but I tried to import the whole module in the click function instead of just doing var couple = new Couple()... now its working. Thanks!